# reset password in codeigniter

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

i am trying to change password in database but it's not working..it printing the password correctly..but it's not save in the database..

Here is my controller:

public function resetpwd($user_id=NULL)
{

```
  //echo $user_id;
$this->load->helper('form');
$data['msg']=array();
if($this->input->post())
  {
   $user_id= $this->input->post('user_id');
  //echo $id; 
   $this->LoginModel->resetpwd($this->input->post(),$user_id);
//redirect(base_url('resetpwd/'.$id));
  }
  $this->load->view('Admin/resetpwd',$data);
```

}

Here is my Model:

```
    function resetpwd($post='',$user_id) 
{

    $data=array('password'=>$post['password']);
    $this->db->where('user_id', $user_id);
    $this->db->update('users', $data);
    return true;
    print_r($data);

}
```

Please help me how to do this

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Please try this code.

```
function resetpwd($post=array(),$user_id)
```

You had passed post array to resetpwd function it is mendatory to get array into array variable.
Change only one line it will be working.

Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply get the password in Model page using post method `extract($_POST)` and you can get your new password like `$data=array('password'=>$password)`

Your Model is-

```
    function resetpwd($user_id) 
{
    extract($_POST);
    $data=array('password'=>$password);
    $this->db->where('user_id', $user_id);
    $this->db->update('users', $data);
    return true;
    //print_r($data);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

please try this code.

Controller :

```
class Adminuser extends CI_Controller {

public function __construct()
  {

    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->model('loginModel'); 
    $this->load->helper('form');

  }

  public function resetpwd() 
{

$data['msg']=array();
if($this->input->post())
  {
   $user_id= $this->input->post('user_id');

   $this->loginModel->change_password($this->input->post('password'),$user_id);

  }
  $this->load->view('Admin/resetpwd',$data);
}

}
```

Your Model Function :

```
public function change_password($password,$user_id) 
{

    $data=array('password'=>$password);
    $this->db->where('user_id', $user_id);

    if($this->db->update('users', $data))
    {
        return true;
    }
    else{
        return false;
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Apply this code

```
function resetpwd($post, $user_id) 
{
    $data=array('password'=>$post['password']);
    $this->db->where('user_id', $user_id);
    $this->db->update('users', $data);
    return true;

}
```

Comment: `print_r($data);` after return ?